# Finding revenue maximizing price with semi-log demand function

Tags: optimization, logarithms

Based on data from a questionnaire I managed to establish the following demand function:

$ln(VR) = -3.521 -0.001*TC$,

where $VR$ is the visitation rate (i.e. the 'quantity demanded' and $TC$ the 'travel cost' is a proxy for the price).
I'm now trying to find the revenue maximizing price based on this. I have tried several approaches, but am always getting stuck somewhere down the line, or my results don't make any sense, and I'm getting pretty desperate.
Is there anybody who could help me out please?

Thanks a million in advance!

Comment: So, you are trying to find the value $x$ that maximizes $\log(y) = a + bx$?

Comment: $\max pq=p*\exp(-3.521-0.001p)$. This can be converted to $\max \{\log(p)-0.001 p\}$ .